# Перевести большое количество UUIDs в ники Mojang API

Tags: python, minecraft

Mojang API позволяет перевести список имён в uuid, например:

```
print(requests.post("https://api.mojang.com/profiles/minecraft", data=json.dumps(["foo", "bar", "nonExistingPlayer"]), headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}).json())
```

Однако я не могу найти способа перевести список uuids в ники, что мне сейчас нужно.
Всё что я нашел, это перевод только одного uuid в ник, например:

```
print(requests.get("https://api.mojang.com/user/profiles/3e3c520c8dd74237a3efef2370b30902/names").json()[-1])
```

Я конечно могу циклом подставить все элементы списка с uuids, но это занимает достаточно много времени и может даже привести к превышению лимита, так как я делаю запрос для 60+ элементов по очереди, это может занять даже 20 секунд!

Comment: Если mojang.com других API не предоставляет, то конечно только по очереди. Поищите другие api или спросите поддержку mojang, если они отвечают. Или сохранять сопоставление где нибудь у себя в БД когда вы получаете какие либо uuid по никам, что бы больше не обращаться к mojang

Comment: Похоже придётся сохранять все запросы ников в БД, тогда будет необходимо каждый месяц запрашивать новые ники, так как люди могут менять имена.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Жаль ты не написал, для чего именно тебе это надо, по этому я опишу несколько решений для разных случаев, так же эти варианты можно объединить

1. Используя прокси ты можешь обойти лимиты API, можешь разбить запросы на N частей и парраллельно вызывать их с разных IP
2. Ты можешь сделать кэш, либо в рантайме, либо в базе данных
3. Ты можешь получать ники по мере их необходимости, банально, но опять же, без контекста не понятно, как это будет использоваться
4. Ты можешь использовать сторонние API, например NameMC

Comment: В моей ситуации остаётся использовать только первый вариант с прокси. В любом случае это было полезно, спасибо!